# How to find out whether installing directory has write permission or not

Tags: windows, directory, nsis, user-permissions

In the installer, User selects a directory and if it doesn't have write permission then nsis installer will go ahead and skip copying files to it and creates an registry entry. It means installation is failed but registry entry is there.
How to find out whether installing directory has write permission or not in nsis ?

Answer (score 1):

This is the pretty much the same issue as: http://forums.winamp.com/showthread.php?t=312637.

(From Afrow UK)

```
ClearErrors
FileOpen $R0 $INSTDIR\tmp.dat w
FileClose $R0
Delete $INSTDIR\tmp.dat
${If} ${Errors}
 ...
 Abort
${EndIf}
```

Basically check the error flag after trying to copy to the directory, if there was an error, then prompt for a different directory. Alternatively you could require admin rights to run the installer.